Agora cloud recording web
I'm trying to record the screen of the conference along with all host interactions.
When I pass location.href as the URL in the payload, the start API works fine, but the stop API returns an error. If I pass google.com then it's getting recorder its not recording my app
 command: "StopCloudRecorder", message: "failed to find worker", subscribeModeBitmask: 4
